# NFS - safely exporting a subdirectory of a filesystem

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

For context, I am assisting in administration of some poorly documented software that uses an NFS mount shared between a primary server and a failover server.  The NFS server is currently exporting a subdirectory of a filesystem, and has no_subtree_check option on for the export, and I am trying to understand the security implications of this and whether it is worth rearranging things so this exported subdirectory lives on its own filesystem instead.

---

According to the exports(5) man page:

> Subdirectory Exports
>
> Normally you should only export only the root of a  filesystem.   The NFS server will also allow you to export a subdirectory of a filesystem, however, this has drawbacks:
>
> First, it may be possible for a  malicious  user  to  access
> files  on  the  filesystem outside of the exported subdirectory, by guessing filehandles for those  other  files.   The
> only  way  to  prevent this is by using the no_subtree_check
> option, which can cause other problems.

Comparing this to the documentation for the options, this last sentence seems backwards to me.  Shouldn't it be the *subtree_check* option which prevents a malicious user from guessing and accessing filehandles outside the exported subdirectory?

This would also seem to match up the "cause other problems" line with the mention elsewhere in the man page about problems with subtree checking:

> From release 1.1.0 of nfs-utils onwards, the  default
> will be no_subtree_check as subtree_checking tends to
> cause more problems than it is worth.

I'm also a little unclear on how filehandle guessing would work.  Is this sort of attack easy to simulate with test commands?  If so, how would I do that?  (If I knew how to do this I could compare subtree_check and no_subtree_check behavior directly.)